# Which is the real database used ? the one in JAR file or the one in resources

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx-8, windows-7-x64, netbeans-8

August 12, 2017

My project Structure is like this……
FamilyTreeV03
•   Src
    o   All my class files
      o DBRoutines.java (this is the one which does all database operations)
•   Resources
    o   Database
           FamilyTreeDB.db (a sqlite database).
    o   Images
           My image files png, jpeg etc.
In my DBRoutines specified the database like

```
private java.sql.Connection RO_Connection;
    private final String sqliteDBname = "jdbc:sqlite:resources/database/FamilyTreeDB.db";
```

…..
Connection is established as follows in a function called DBConnect().

```
RO_Connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(sqliteDBname);
```

In the project settings I have included resources directory and resources (I think it goes into Build-impl.xml !!!!

For the images, I have specified the path as

```
File thisImageFile;
if (Gender == "Male") {
    thisImageFile = new File("resources\\Images\\Gentleman.jpg");
} else {
    thisImageFile = new File("resources\\Images\\Lady.jpg");
}
```

I did a clean and build of this project and everything worked fine from Netbeans IDE. 
The database was sitting in G:\64BitJavaPrograms\FamilyTreeV03\build\classes\Database directory. Don’t ask me why & the images where sitting under G:\64BitJavaPrograms\FamilyTreeV03\build\classes\Images.

While I tried to execute from command prompt from DIST directory…It could not see the database or images. They were sitting inside the JAR file under DATABASE or IMAGES directories. Which is not visible to the code in DBRoutines.java. I had to copy the RESOURCES directory to DIST directory and everything works fine.

Now there will be TWO SQLITE databases in DIST directory, one within the JAR file and the other in RESOURCES/DATABASE directory.

I AM CONFUSED.

.

Can someone help.... I want to use only the database file which sits in the JAR file. How to do that.

Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

My directory structure for sources is project\src for source files and project\resources\database for database file and project\resources\images for my image files.

Database routine defined the database as follows.

```
private final String sqliteDBname = "jdbc:sqlite:resources/database/FamilyTreeDB.db";
RO_Connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(sqliteDBname);
```

In Build.xml I added,

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <copy todir="dist/resources/database">
        <fileset dir="build/classes/database"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="dist/resources/images">
        <fileset dir="build/classes/images"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Output is project\dist\resources\database, project\dist\resources\images and project\dist\project.jar. The jar file did not have a copy of the database file, sitting inside.

Thanks for everyone who looked at this.....